# Alive time in xamarin

Tags: android, datetime, xamarin, time

I have this code:

```
    int h = DateTime.Now.Hour;
    int m = DateTime.Now.Minute;
    int s = DateTime.Now.Second;
    textTime.Text = h.ToString() + ":" + m.ToString() + ":" + s.ToString();
```

But this code is not alive.

Comment: "this code is not alive" - what do you mean?  What is it doing (or not doing) that is different than what you expect?

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to find out how long the app has been running for?

Comment: Hours, minutes and seconds are fixed and they do not change.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure I understand your question, but maybe you want to use a StopWatch?  You would need to "start" and "stop" it when necessary to get the elapsed time corrrect

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
sw.Stop();
var text = string.Format( "{0}:{1}:{2}", sw.Elapsed.Hours, sw.Elapsed.Minutes, sw.Elapsed.Seconds );
```